# T-SQL: UPDATE table according to a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

**TLDNR**: how do I update a table depending on a column?

**Problem situation**: the current column `SortingNumber` is full of bad data.

**Solution**: reassign new values to `SortingNumber` based on their `Parent`. The `SortingNumber` shall be 1 for the lowest current `SortingNumber` *(by `Parent`)* and be incremented by 1 for every subsequent dataset.

```
Current data:                         Desired result:

ID | Parent | SortingNumber   >>      ID | Parent | SortingNumber 
1  |   1    |   3             >>      1  |   1    |   1 
2  |   1    |   4             >>      2  |   1    |   2 
3  |   1    |   5             >>      3  |   1    |   3 
4  |   2    |   8             >>      4  |   2    |   1           
5  |   2    |   10            >>      5  |   2    |   2           
6  |   2    |   13            >>      6  |   2    |   3
```

**Actual problem**: I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the datasets corresponding to their parents.

My script currently updates all the values incrementally and doesn't group it by `Parent`.

My current solution:

```
DECLARE @lastSN INTEGER = 0;

WITH toUpdate AS
(
    SELECT 
        T1.*,
        -- "calculate" the sorting number from the row above    
        LAG(T1.SortingNumber + 1, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY T1.SortingNumber) AS [newSortNumber]
    FROM 
        T AS T1 
    INNER JOIN 
        T AS T2 ON T1.Parent = T2.ID
)
UPDATE toUpdate
SET
    @lastSN = CASE WHEN [newSortNumber] = 1 AND @lastSN = 0 THEN 1 ELSE @lastSN + 1 END,
    toUpdate.SortingNumber = @lastSN 
;
```

Result is:

```
    ID | Parent | SortingNumber   
    1  |   1    |   1             
    2  |   1    |   2             
    3  |   1    |   3             
    4  |   2    |   4             
    5  |   2    |   5            
    6  |   2    |   6
```

I guess my question could be phrased as: how do I update datasets depending on the `Parent` column?

*PS*: here is the `CREATE` statement if you wish to try it out yourself

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Parent INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T(ID),
    SortingNumber INT
);   
GO  

INSERT INTO T (Parent, SortingNumber) 
VALUES (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 13);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ `row_number` to achieve this using partitioning by `Parent` and ordering by `SortingNumber`.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    * ,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY SortingNumber) AS NewSortingNumber
FROM T

)
UPDATE cte
SET SortingNumber = NewSortingNumber
```

A window function creates small tables within the table using Parent, so we have two subsets, one for Parent = 1 and the another for Parent = 2. Then it uses `ORDER BY` to know from which row it should start count (starting from 1). The first row is for  Parent = 1 and ID =1  so it gets 1, the next row gets 2 etc. Please look here for more [details](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/).

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can just rank, ordering by patient then ID:

```
UPDATE tt

SET sortingnumber = drank from (select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by Parent, ID) as drank from tt ) a where tt.ID=a.id and tt.parent=a.parent

select * from tt
```

Comment: Doesn't yield the wanted result, but thanks for the input. The [answer of M. Kanarkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751873/5757162) does actually achive what i need :)